# Inline svg vs svg Sprite vs multiple external files

Tags: svg, webpack, inline-svg, svg-sprite, svg-sprite-loader

OK so i am building a web app using Laravel & Vue js mainly. I tried to use https://github.com/JetBrains/svg-sprite-loader#installation but the exported svg shows up blank.

In that context before proceeding, i started wondering if this is really worth it and tbh, i am not sure.

So my question is, what is really the difference?

Let's assume we can't use icon fonts, because we want to have multicoloured svgs.

- Is it even worth trying to use a package to merge the svgs into a sprite and then use it, or does it not really make a difference with http/2?
- Considering file size and data usage, is it worth trying to minimise this aspect using sprite instead of multiple external svg files?
- Inlining the svgs is also an option but this would dramatically increase the dom size.

So i am left wondering... has anyone tried out all these techniques and figured out the best and most performant one and what are their true differences.

Lastly if anyone would give me some input on why my svg sprite shows blank, it would be a huge bonus :P

I have configured the above package in my webpack.mix like so:

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const SpriteLoaderPlugin = require('svg-sprite-loader/plugin');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .webpackConfig({
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /resources\/images\/.*\.svg$/,
                    loader: 'svg-sprite-loader',
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    options: {
                        extract: true,
                        spriteFilename: 'icons-sprite.svg',
                        publicPath: 'images/sprites/',
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new SpriteLoaderPlugin({ plainSprite: true}) // Sprites Plugin.
        ],
    })
    .version()
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is it even worth trying to use a package to merge the svgs into a sprite and then use it, or does it not really make a difference with http/2?

It does matter, but depends on your use case. You would have to test on your **production** environment yourself. Ofcourse HTTP/2 is always better

> Considering file size and data usage, is it worth trying to minimise this aspect using sprite instead of multiple external svg files?

same answer as 1.. Use Case. Comes down to *estimating* (because you can't calculate it) how long Browser A has to wait for new content.

GZip is the most important factor for data usage.

On slow 3G connections adding your own LZMA compression for (large) files *could* be interesting.

> Inlining the svgs is also an option but this would dramatically increase the dom size.

You are still sending the same bytes, only in a different file, might even be better because of GZip working on everything in one file.

In general my advice is to not worry about performance; it is not an OR-OR decision.

Start with seperate files, only re-factor when you *hit* performance issues.
Maybe develop with refactoring in mind if you *expect* performance issues.

#### Alternative: *Create* SVG Client Side

I went one step further. Became an experiment how small/fast I could go:

- Reworked all SVG to String notation `<circle cx='20' cy='20' r='5'/>` becomes `c:20,20,5`
- Used in one JS file
- parse the Strings **Client** Side
- to create SVG
- used in a DataURI IMG src

This got **550 KB** in 52 SVG files down to **16 KB** in **one** Custom Element file

- https://cardmeister.github.io/
- https://github.com/cardmeister/cardmeister.github.io

[image]

## and GZip is an important factor!

GZip compresses the Server side file before it is send to the Client.

Yes minification is important, but minification *can* have a negative effect on GZip compression.

Good read from a long time ago:

https://encode.su/threads/1889-gzthermal-pseudo-thermal-view-of-Gzip-Deflate-compression-efficiency

It explains why `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` is bad, and `<!doctype html>` is good.

The same applies to SVG files: `<circle ...` is better than `<CIRCLE ...`

and

`<circle fill='...' cx='20' .../>` is better than `<circle cx='20' ... fill='...'/>`

Because GZip finds a longer **repeating** pattern `<circle fill='`

Comment: Ok so if i understand correctly:
- Inlining the svgs is never the best solution, if we are talking about a process that would dynamically generate multiple svgs since it is ALMOST the same as if we were using separate, files but would increase the dom size.
- Sprites are always better performance wise, but should evaluate if the implementation time is worth it.
- Should go about it by trial and error because it is not really possible to evaluate if it is worth or not.
Would the technique you suggest be a feasible approach if I would like to implement server side rendering in the future? TY

Comment: The alternative is only worth the effort if you serve many users and traffic has a (notable) price. Inline in an HTML file or one SVG file with symbols is no difference, they are the same bytes only in a different file. No difference when adding SSR. For everything: People think it is about minified files; it is not, it is all about GZip: https://encode.su/threads/1889-gzthermal-pseudo-thermal-view-of-Gzip-Deflate-compression-efficiency

Comment: I guess an argument could be made about caching. I guess when the doc's cache is invalidated for whatever reason inline svgs are loader normally, while if you are referencing a separate cached svg file. (Disclaimer: i am not "yet :P" so educated about the full caching cycle). Also would you answer change if we consider that we will probably have some svgs repeating themselves a lot (e.g. a page with teasers of some entity, that use the same svg for some indication)?

Comment: Yes, and then there is Client side caching (maybe even use localStorage to store content) and Server side caching. You say *repeating a lot*, then stick to one file... because then caching is the most important part. It is all about thinking where/how/when every byte is transferred.. But in the end: The Nike approach: Just do IT.. start developing.